# Understanding たところ in this context?

Tags: grammar

> 重戦車型の索敵能力は低い。
>
> 指揮官機であるレイもそれに漏れず、何機も従えた斥候型や指揮下の本隊のそれとリンクすることで索敵能力を補っている。けれど従えた斥候型は全滅してしまったし、本隊も最初の指示だけ与えてほったらかした**ところ**散々にやられて撤退を始めている。レイにしてみればシンを連れ帰るのが第一の目的でその他は二の次だったので、放っておいたのだが。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Does this たところ use the construction in this link? Namely, the enemies’ withdrawal is considered as an unexpected finding?

https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/09/14/jlptn3-grammar-tatokoro/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it uses the same construction in the link as in "〜したら〜になった".

---

However, note that the page says:

> 普通の出来事の説明ではなく、驚きや新しい発見があったことを説明する時に使う。

This is not necessarily true. I can prove this easily:

---

Let me introduce you to a word to express "as expected" (which is the opposite of unexpected) : "案の定". And let me sneak that in to your sentence:

> 本隊も最初の指示だけ与えてほったらかしたところ**案の定**散々にやられて撤退を始めている。

This doesn't sound strange to me. Let's take a look at another example, this time from that exact link:

> レシピどおりに作ってみたところ、美味しく作ることができました。

How is this supposed to be surprising?

---

Therefore, "〜ところ" doesn't necessarily mean "unexpectedly it turned out to be〜". It sure may be used to express "unexpectedly" depending on the context though.

Having said that, the link you pasted seems to be designed towards JLPT which is much reputable than strangers on a forum. **If** their guideline really defines "〜ところ" as a phrase used to express elements of surprise, then I'd recommend you comply/trust them over my answer, at least until you are confident enough to make your own decision.